# Routing documents to multiple receivers in Biztalk 2016

Tags: xml, ftp, port, sftp, biztalk

I need to archive documents sent to a customer on an internal folder in the sender system. The documents are stored on an SFTP and are delivered to an external FTP. The SFTP adapter deletes the file after it has been picked up.

A copy of all the documents that are picked up by the SFTP adapter needs to be moved to another folder in the sender system. I tried creating another receive location for this purpose, but since the files are being deleted when they are picked up, it's a race of when gets to pick up the files first.

How can I achieve this in Biztalk? I considered creating a send port group, but as the files need to be sent to 8 different folders depending on the filename, I can't just set up a filter to send all the files to all the send ports that have been created.

I'd like to avoid using orchestrations if possible, as we use internal ones for routing documents correctly through out system.

Comment: What are the exact archive requirements *that the business has provided to you*?  Have you properly setup Tracking?  Most 'archiving' is based on phantom requirements so it's important to know exactly what you need to implement.

Comment: So what is wrong with a Send Port group?  That is what it is useful for.  Setting up the same filter on multiple send ports is fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple send ports means your message will be duplicated to all those send ports, if the filter matches. Like a subscription. You don't need a send port group. Just a separate send port with a filter on your receive location will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I have since figured out another solution to my problem, but I will mark this as answered.